# Can I use ${entityName} in a filter to sort out the device in the entity Table?

Tags: filter, thingsboard

Scenario:
Device Name Pattern: SensorType-BuildingName-Sensor#
Dashboard the main page to a different sub-page (device table page) using the "${entityName}" function, and the title of the sub-page is able to show the building Name.

I want to use Building Name to filter out some sensors which don't belong to the building.
I tried to use the "${entityName} function in "filters value" but it wasn't successful. I also tried to use hardcode to key in the building name in "filters value", it can filter out the unused devices.

is it possible to filter out unused devices automatically by selecting building from the main page to a different sub-page?

the expected result is that it can automatically filter out unused devices when I select a building from the main page to a different sub-page.